# Is it OK to group form elements into "p"?

Tags: html, xhtml, semantics

Let's say I have this code

```
<form action="#" method="get">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Is it semanticaly fine to group elements with **p**? Because my teacher (again.. I know ..:P) told me that **p** should be used only for paragraph and that I should use **div** instead, but as I can see, **p** is used a lot and almost everywhere.

The last possibility I can think of is `<br />`, which I think is the worst way.

So which one is the best to use

- wrap by `<div>`
- wrap by `<p>`
- `<br />` at the end

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Check out this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109488/is-it-bad-design-to-use-table-tags-when-displaying-forms-in-html) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860745/p-vs-ol-or-ul-for-form-styling).

Honestly, I don't think it's a huge deal, but using `<fieldset>` is probably the most semantically correct way that will make your teacher happy. In the real world, though, I group forms by `<p>` sometimes.

Comment: I agree with this answer. You could treat <fieldset> the same as <p>. Plus, some extra features such as using the <legend> as a child element. All this, and the fact that this is what <fieldset> is made more.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most semantic way is to do it with a list element, like described in [Prettier Accessible Forms](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms), since most forms is actually much like a list of fields to fill out, I figure it makes the most sense, semantically.

If you want to have a group of fields, fieldset is good for that, but I almost always put each form item in a `<li>`.

Comment: fieldset is probably better, but li is situationally a very likely candidate

Comment: dl with dt for labels and dd for fields ("to-be-filled definitions") may fit too.

Comment: me in faviour of using li inside field sets.. for ordering numerous related fields inside a common fieldset

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, I would (in this case) agree with your teacher and prefer <div> over <p>.

Answer (score 1):

I use `<div class="field">...</div>` for individual form fields and `<fieldset>...</fieldset>` for groups of related fields.

For the buttons at the end of the form (submit/reset/back/etc) I use `<fieldset class="controls">...</fieldset>`

(I also have a set of CFML custom tag scripts which generate the HTML for me, so I can just write, for example, `<form:edit id="MyField" label="My Field" ...etc... />` and it produces the appropriate HTML without needing lots of repetitive sourcecode.)

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is correct. P = paragraph. So ask yourself the question, is it a paragraph of text? If not don't use it.

You wouldn't play football with a cricket ball just because it's round

Comment: Was very confused as an American reading the last sentence. "Footballs aren't round!" ...Then it came to me :-)

Comment: LOL, I suppose I should have chosen something that translates more universally

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap it using `<div/>` and then style appropriately using CSS.

It seems to me a much cleaner separation of the structure of the page versus the layout/styling of that page. e.g. you're at liberty later to style it for different devices, print ec.

Answer (score 0):

Neither, IMO.

Fieldset combined with a list (or maybe even a table) is far more semantically correct.

- P is wrong plainly because a form just is not a paragraph.
- DIV has no semantic meaning whatsoever - it's just "part of something", so using it alone to contain the form makes no sense.
- Splitting by BR has no purpose, as you can just as well provide styling on your labels and/or input-fields to simulate the line break.